# Is this post data making two requests?

Tags: c#, web, http-post

I have taken the following code from Stackoverflow and used it in my web application. I'm currently facing an issue where if I use this method to submit my username and password with incorrect credentials, it's getting counted twice at the target website.

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://www.yoursite.com");
request.Method = "POST";

formContent = "Username=" + someValue +
"&Password" + someValue2;

byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(formContent);
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
dataStream.Close();
WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
string responseFromServer = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(reader.ReadToEnd());

reader.Close();
dataStream.Close();
response.Close();
```

I want to know if the double request is being caused by the following two lines each making a request in the code snippet above:

```
Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: why don't you debug it yourself? wouldn't it be easier to put a breakpoint and do a debug and observe what happens actually?

Comment: If it was this code that was duplicating your requests, you wouldn't only see it happening with "incorrect credentials". What are the contents of the requests? Are they identical?

Comment: mentat - I would love to but I'm in a situation where our test environment that acts as a proxy between my machine and the endpoint is currently broken (that's a whole story in itself).

haxard - There is a system on the other end that tracks how many incorrect logins there are that I do not have access to. My problem is that a user is allowed 6 incorrect credentials before they get locked out but because of this double request they are getting locked out after 3

Answer (score 0):

In short, yes: the "double request is being caused by the following two lines each making a request in the code snippet above".

Each of those methods are performing a request on their own.

Documentation from [GetResponse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.getresponse(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_2):

> The GetResponse method returns a WebResponse object that contains the response from the Internet resource. The actual instance returned is an HttpWebResponse, and can be typecast to that class to access HTTP-specific properties.

Documentation from [GetRequestStream](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d4cek6cc(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_2):

> The GetRequestStream method returns a stream to use to send data for the HttpWebRequest. After the Stream object has been returned, you can send data with the HttpWebRequest by using the Stream.Write method.
>   If an application needs to set the value of the ContentLength property, then this must be done before retrieving the stream.
>   You must call the Stream.Close method to close the stream and release the connection for reuse. Failure to close the stream causes your application to run out of connections.

Comment: Thanks for that. I've already seen that documentation. Can anyone suggest an alternative to the above code to post the same data with only one post?

Comment: No problem!  Does [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/debx8sh9(v=vs.100).aspx) help suggest a course of action?